# Adding and subtracting selected radio buttons based on their values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of script that counts the number of meats chosen from an series of radio buttons, and changes "Select meats" to "*x* meats chosen". This is how it starts.

```
$('input.meats').not('[value=None]').on('click', function() {
    var count = $('input.meats:checked').length;
    $('.select-meats span').text(count+' meats chosen');
});
```

This is how my form starts.

```
Chicken:   X None   _ Half   _ Full
Beef:      X None   _ Half   _ Full
Pork:      X None   _ Half   _ Full
Select meats.
```

If I change the selection, "Select meats" changes to the total selected meats. It doesn't matter if it's Half or Full.

```
Chicken:   X None   _ Half   _ Full
Beef:      _ None   X Half   _ Full
Pork:      _ None   _ Half   X Full
2 meats chosen.
```

My problem is if I changes one of the selected meats back to none, it does not subtract from the total.

```
Chicken:   X None   _ Half   _ Full
Beef:      _ None   X Half   _ Full
Pork:      X None   _ Half   _ Full
2 meats chosen.                       <-- Should be "1 meats chosen".
```

How can I get it to subtract itself from the total should I change the selection back to "None"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `not()` in the wrong place. By putting it on the event handler registration, your code won't be run when the user presses the `None` option. By not putting it in your `count` calculation, you were counting `None` as 1 meat.

Move the `.not('[value=None]')` into your `count` calculation and out of the event handler registration:

```
$('input.meats').on('click', function() {
    var count = $('input.meats:checked').not('[value=None]').length;
    $('.select-meats span').text(count+' meats chosen');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `not` on the count variable like so:

```js
$('input.meats').on('click', function() {
  var count = $('input.meats:checked').not('[value=none]').length;
  $('.selected-meats span').text(count+' meats chosen');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input class="meats" name="chicken" type="radio" value="none"> None<br>
  <input class="meats" name="chicken" type="radio" value="half"> Half<br>
  <input class="meats" name="chicken" type="radio" value="full"> Full
  <hr>
  <input class="meats" name="beef" type="radio" value="none"> None<br>
  <input class="meats" name="beef" type="radio" value="half"> Half<br>
  <input class="meats" name="beef" type="radio" value="full"> Full
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr>
  <div class="selected-meats">
    <span></span>
  </div>
```